# OAuth signature check only by url w/o anything else?

Tags: oauth

Is it possible that I just verify oauth_signature only via a url?

I have OAuth consumer secret, but i **don't** have token secret, I'm in a position like man-in-middle, but i don't want to change anything, but just verify whether this oauth request is valid or not. All what i get is a simple url containing standard things like:

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_token
- oauth_signature_method (always HMAC-SHA1)
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_signature.

Can i use these thing to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check if the request is valid, as in authenticated, that would mean that you have managed to hack the OAuth provider, and this should not be possible unless you have managed to get a hold of the consumer and token secret.

If you simply want to check if the request contains the needed parameters in a well formed OAuth request, then you are almost there.

But, `oauth_version` parameter is also needed on all requests, should always be `1.0` for a valid OAuth 1.0a request.

If the request is for an access token then an `oauth_verifier` should be there as well.

If the request is for a request token, then `oauth_token` is not needed.

Comment: can you take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238779/ios-oauth-signature-fails-with-invalid-signature-error